# Include directories

Tags: premake

My project has the following structure:

[image]

And include my include directories like this

```
includedirs {
        "ext/openssl-1.0.2f/include",
        "ext/easyloggingpp/src",
        "ext/pugixml/src",
        "ext/sfml-2.3.2/include"
    }
```

But in my cpp files I need to add the includes like this

`#include "../../ext/openssl-1.0.2f/include/openssl/bio.h"`

How can I include the file by just stating `#include "openssl/bio.h"`?

Here is an updated project structure:

The generated files are under the **workspace** directory

[image]

Partial of the **openssl** directory

[image]

Comment: where is your .lua located ? And also, in your project file (or makefile) what are the generated include directories ?

Comment: @Citron: The ,lua file is in the root of the project. The VS2015 project file has this - <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>..\ext\openssl-1.0.2f\include;..\ext\easyloggingpp\src; - I only include a portion of that entry.

Comment: Can you show a project tree that includes your Lua file(s) and the generated project files so we can see where they live, and what the include paths ought to be? It is kind of hard to make suggestions with only a partial view of the project. Thanks!

Comment: @starkos: The second image that I attached (partial of the openssl directory) I would like to include in my project as `#include <openssl/aes.h>` for example. Or any other include as `#include "config/config.h"`

Answer (score 0):

Although you dont really mention it in your question I conclude from your tags that you are using `premake`.
I use the `includedirs {"relativepath1", "relativepath2", ... }` of premake. It adds the directories to your compilers *include paths* and you can include them like that:

```
#include <Header.h> || #include "Header.h"
```

Also see the [documentation](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/includedirs)