# How to link Google Test with premake5

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest, premake

I want to link Google Test (https://github.com/google/googletest) with my project. I added gtest as submodule in following directory:
`%{wks.location}/sengine/vendor/gtest`
I have following premake5 script in gtest directory:

```
project "gtest"
kind "StaticLib"
language "C++"

targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

files
{
    "googletest/include/gtest/**.h",
    "googletest/src/gtest-all.cc",
}

filter "system:windows"
    systemversion "latest"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "On"

filter "configurations:Debug"
    runtime "Debug"
    symbols "on"

filter "configurations:Release"
    runtime "Release"
    optimize "on"
```

Errors like this unveil:

```
D:\dev\sengine\sengine\vendor\gtest\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc(38,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h': No such file or directory
```

I don't really know how should I change my script so I can for example include gtest.h like this:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

googletest expects that the directory `googletest/include` dir is a root include directory. You can infer this because `<>` are used (compared to `""` for relative paths in the project) and the path is given relative to this directory in `gtest-all.cc`.

I work more with CMake an have no experience with premake5 but usually you need to specify include directory roots manually.

Apparently premake5 has a similar mechanism: [Include directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390279/include-directories)